# How to make Matplotlib installed also available for python 3 on sublime text 3

Tags: python, matplotlib, sublimetext3

I am trying to import python modules into sublime text 3. I have installed matplotlib, but my Mac has both python 2 and python 3, so it turns out to be that the matplotlib works for python 2, but not for python 3 (no module named matplotlib).

So, is there anyway I can make matplotlib also available for python 3? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment, so I'll just post my answer here.

If you have both `python2` and `python3` installed, you can install packages for python3 by `pip3`. Try this:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

If you just use pip:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

you are installing `matplotlib` for `python2`. It is not recommended to use system python (which is python2) on macOS. So I recommend that you install any packages with `pip3` from now on.

Comment: Oh, ok! Got it.Thank you so much!